# Entity Framework code-first targeting LocalDb instead of local SQL Server Express host

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

In a new development project using Entity Framework 6.0 code-first I had to update my models quite a bit. The update script that was automatically generated using `Add-Migration` in Package Manager Console got quite complex so I decided to start over. To do this I deleted the database from localhost and deleted the `Migrations` folder in the project. However when I re-ran the `Add-Migration`-command I got the following message and the same update-script was generated again:

> The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your
>   current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the
>   changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration.

I was fairly certain this was because `__MigrationHistory`-table was still there somehow. I went into the database again but nothing had been created and the database was still gone.

Connection string used in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WebApp;Integrated Security=sspi;Pooling=false;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I then checked my processes and saw two versions of the `sqlservr.exe`-process and LocalDb came to mind. I connected to `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and there was a new database named 'DefaultConnection' with all tables for the project. When I deleted this database I got a fresh script from the `Add-Migration`-command. Somewhere along the line a switch must have been made since I'm 100% certain I have been working against the SQL Server Express host at some time (All tables prior to the update script where there when I deleted the database) and for all my other project localhost works with `Data Source=localhost`. I can't understand why the database name is `DefaultConnection` instead of `WebApp` either. Connecting to localhost, the database name was `WebApp`. Has anyone experienced this before?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found an answer to it. In Package Manager Console it is not enough to set `Default project` to the project containing `DbContext` you **ALSO need to make sure that your website is set as the Default StartUp Project!**

This small change made everything work normal again.

I cannot find this documented anywhere so I hope it will help someone.

Comment: regardless of my CS. It is using localDb and not a sql server developer edition. It also names the database after my connection name and namespace. I called it DEEBEE and it created DAL.DEEBEE.
I'm still stuck.